# Where to define common methods to be used in services

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I can use my `application_controller` to define common methods that I can then use in all my controllers. I'm looking for the same idea, but for `services` I've created. Within my app my `services` folder is on the same level as `models` and `controllers`.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [inheritance](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_inheritance.html) or `Modules` and include/extend them.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to structure your services like the controllers and models, then I would say defining an `application_service` and having all other services inherit from it would be a good way to go about it